# List of foreign keys in an insert SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set up a stored proc that will have three variables

1. FK_List
2. String_of_Info
3. CreateId

I need to insert into the table one entry per foreign key from the FK_List. I was curious what the best way to structure the stored procedure to do this efficiently.

EDIT: Code snippet added

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StackOverFlowExample_BulkAdd 
    @FKList VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Notes NVARCHAR(1000),
    @CreateId VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflowTable] WITH (ROWLOCK)
           ([FKID], [Notes], [CreateId], [UpdateId])
    VALUES (@FKList, <---- this is the problem spot
            @Notes, @CreateId, @CreateId)
END
GO
```

Comment: What are you going to insert? Random garbage data?

Comment: I added a small sample so you can see data types

Comment: You need to learn how to pass multiple values into a stored procedure -- say using a table variable rather than a string

Comment: Are you using the same value for Notes for all rows?

Comment: @scsimon yes I am.

Comment: @maxsands1503 Can't you make the `FKID` column in `StackOverflowTable` table `UNIQUE`? Or use `IF EXISTS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your comments, you simply need a slight edit

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StackOverFlowExample_BulkAdd 
    @Notes nvarchar(1000),
    @CreateId varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflowTable] WITH (ROWLOCK)
           ([FKID]
           ,[Notes]
           ,[CreateId]           
           ,[UpdateId])
     select
           someID
           ,@Notes
           ,@CreateId           
           ,@CreateId
     from FKListTable
END
GO
```

**[Here is a simple demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95fa2816567ce1756c20d9c5f4404cb4)**

This will insert a row into your table for each FK reference in the reference table with the parameters you pass in. That's all there is to it!

[Here's another demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5811756134f8550d801ca5414149cfdb) that may be more clear as I use a GUID for the primary key on the secondary table.

**SECOND EDIT**

Based off your comments, you will need a string splitter. I have added a common one which was created by [Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). **[See the example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a13c584701e456705693d01302dfa92)**

The final proc, after you create the function, will be like below. You need to change the comma in the function to what ever the delimiter is for your application. Also, you should start using [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StackOverFlowExample_BulkAdd 
    @FKList VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Notes nvarchar(1000),
    @CreateId varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflowTable] WITH (ROWLOCK)
           ([FKID]
           ,[Notes]
           ,[CreateId]           
           ,[UpdateId])
    select item 
           ,@Notes
           ,@CreateId           
           ,@CreateId
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@FKList,',')
END
```

And you can call it like so:

```
declare @FKList varchar(1000) = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
declare @Notes varchar(1000) = 'here is my note'
declare @CreatedId int = 1

exec StackOverFlowExample_BulkAdd @FKList, @Notes, @CreatedId
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the list of FK are coming from user selections on the front end and being passed to the procedure via the API.

Comment: so the parameter is a delimited list? I assume since you have `varchar(max)` as the datatype

Comment: The parameter will be sent by the API as a delimited list delimited list

Comment: @scsimon Note to `STRING_SPLIT()` function if the OP on 2016+

Comment: They didn't specify and not many folks are on that version so i usually don't include it, but it would be a preferred method.

Comment: @scsimon I mean add it as a note in your answer ("If you are on 2016+ version you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` function"). :)